# Pytesseract struggling to pick up custom fonts

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have a seemingly standard set of digits which pytesseract can not seem to pick up.

I have attached the image of the text I am trying to match. Is there anything I am missing from this?

Many thanks!

[image: 1]

My code is below:

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('img_test.png')
img = cv2.resize(img, (600, 360))
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img = cv2.threshold(img, 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
# img = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)


data = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng', config='--psm 6')
print(data)


cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.imwrite('img.png', img)
cv2.waitKey()
```

I have gone through previous posts without much luck so far!

Comment: pure ocr issue. opencv is an innocent bystander.